# How to mmap different regions of the same file into different memory addresses?

Tags: linux, system-calls, mmap, loader

How can I  mmap different parts of a file into different memory regions?

I tried with this code, but get `File exists` errors:

```
int fd = open(FN, O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
       perror("");
       exit(1);
}
void* retval;
retval = mmap((void*) 0x00401000, 0xb93, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC, MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0x1000);
if (retval == MAP_FAILED) {
       perror("Error mmap 1");
       exit(1);
}
   
retval = mmap((void*) 0x00402000, 0x660, PROT_READ, MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0x2000);
if (retval == MAP_FAILED) {
       perror("Error mmap 2");
       exit(1);
}
```

The first mmap works fine; the second fails with `File exists`.  If I comment out the first one, the second works.

I get this error whether I do `MMAP_PRIVATE` or `MMAP_SHARED`.  Likewise, I get the error if I reuse the original fd, or open a new fd to the same file.

How can I mmap two regions of the same file to different places? Why can't I do this directly, given that the mmap is read only (no `PROT_WRITE`) and also copy-on-write (`MMAP_PRIVATE`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `length` field in the mmap calls, not the fact that it's the same file.  Note the length is `0xb932`, `0x660`, but these are rounded up by mmap to 0x1000.  Thus, the pages end up taking more memory than expected, causing collisions, which, due to `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`, the kernel is unable to replace and fix.

Comment: Even without any rounding up the first `mmap` already overlaps with the second one, so the rounding is not causing the issue here.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Thanks, that was a typo, fixed